# Applying a single-qubit Pauli measurement to 3 or more pure non-orthogonal $n$-qubit stabilizer states

Tags: pauli-group, stabilizer-state

Given 3 (or more) pure non-orthogonal $n$-qubit stabilizer states where the number of qubits $n \ge 2$, say $|\psi_1\rangle,|\psi_2\rangle,|\psi_3\rangle$, define $|\nu\rangle\langle \nu |$ as a single qubit Pauli measurement (in some basis) on the final qubit.

The resulting measured states are $\{\langle{\nu}|\psi_1\rangle,\langle{\nu}|\psi_2\rangle,\langle{\nu}|\psi_3\rangle\}$.

Is it true that there always exists a choice of basis $\nu$ such that the result of the single-qubit Pauli measurement will map these states to a set of post-measurement states with more than one state? I.e., that the set of post-measurement states are not all the same state.

Source of claim: https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.07744

Comment: Your question is not clear. What does the last phrase, "with more than one state", mean? Please try to rewrite your question with additional details.